# How to define object accepted argument type for function in typescript

Tags: typescript

Lets say I want to define a function that accepts one argument that must be an object which keys are strings and values can be for example `number | string` like it done in the bottom example.

```
const fn = (param: Record<string, string | number>) => {
  console.log(param);
};

const p = {
  id: 1,
  name: 'John'
};

fn(p);
```

the above example will work just fine, but when I want to give an explicit type to variable `p` with using typescript's `type` as in the bottom example, everything working just fine again.

```js
const fn = (param: Record<string, string | number>) => {
  console.log(param);
};

type User = {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

const p: User = {
  id: 1,
  name: 'John'
};

fn(p);
```

But when defining type with the typescript `interface` as in the example below I'm getting an error saying

`TS2345: Argument of type 'User' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Record<string, string | number>'`.

 `Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type 'User'.`

```
const fn = (param: Record<string, string | number>) => {
  console.log(param);
};

interface User {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

const p: User = {
  id: 1,
  name: 'John'
};

fn(p);
```

So what is the reason for such a behavior?
How can I define type for function argument to be an object which keys should be `string` and values can be union type for example `string | number` and will work with both `type`s and `interface`s?

Answer (score 2):

This should be due to the fact that interfaces are "open" while type aliases are closed, meaning they can not be extended after their initial declaration, unlike interfaces, that can be declared again - which means you could add properties to the interface, that are not assignable to `Record<string, string | number>`. This also relates to [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#:%7E:text=For%20the%20purposes%20of%20this,both%20of%20the%20original%20declarations.)

See this [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBUAsFMCdtAQ3qALgdwPagLaIJYB2ammANgM4mgAm0AxmcgqjKBZIgA4KYBmSQgFgAUCFCYARgCsGqAFygiqOH0T1oVRIRpoAnjyRl8iCpoB0okFbBRoepCgBucBxXw58TWABpBuvkxYNDYcTApUUHpMHDDielNNGyR6SNYECkQcaEsRUVQDBAAhfFgacELQAF5QAG9RUFB0IgBzCkUAJgBuUQBfHryRZVV1YtKaAElCFVg1DTqGptb20G6%200VFowgjQSXGARkUSsorDGtqlwjbO0H7NzG3IvbKOo-GpmbmEc8vr1duBskigxEABXMwQQoAZXosHwXEi%20C07FQsFBqVBsEQZH0hgoegi0BwPmS%20FQAHIqFxwu5JGQWNhhrBPAAPELQUqgcEMzC5e6PXbjADMbzKHxG8xqzxo%200BYlsMAckkwrHYoK41NgkWgLJUOlaEnSwSZXy0OlxFmSpwQ2JMZioNGwrCRoCcJiU0zgZlS%20AeFoofnQkC80FJntmoyonBcSFAAGt7FgynyRAVDAB5dA4n6ETAY2CEbGKVGghC9UAAMlAx3KhQGaYQACUpERqnVQLn84WyIo1JQy5Xq%209w185SbRqAAArQdR5uOgHV6mhUGvWhYiRrRMiYTF8UE9tBo6ADRp8YyaXvYswDXqicfzADCwfoCeIi%20gOhXw8%20E-qG6i5A7rM%206Xv2J6gGe%20AXhBV7Husgz0pEmBZoombZu2zRXCsHR%20J2qCYt2xZHgCoiIVEz6vooT74C%20H5thcmF-DhAHbruIEwf2fiQdBfYQncgziFAiCRJk%20A0IGCDwNEsQfroeg7lyEL3poEguMEDbJLaiQUOYoBQjw9D4HwNHYmQeh%20JIILcqA8mgksZA4i00BPM5MwLrAsBBMk2QUJkTk6aAEwCLZoCQJgamqXA7IQeQ26Me5nmwAGNkKQkwjyuw0AIGF6CQjwMJwgiUTaKAXCeW6dBoF6UXaLoYQoIE9DcjQ3maH5KlBnRSZxgazSqspVDGAmoDUbRhApsh6H0BRH4DNNNGvm2k1yuI6aEAgeDSEEtBGXwcAfvMlkYFlxANkYdoqU4VADZpKCsMJHo-hoWgoJgPDELVFrndpjgIIw4TQDQuSCcGVDZNoVAhWlC66rJgiPRKCCSA4dCMMgBpkppmVbLoqAeDkGxDCOE4ANJknq66NFwmJJYoyrkDOhA3oTymgGTqAU3%20m6AZiigRHCVzMwJYBTNFKowMECQQogX1pbmLnkdoTm6DuqDuJV-CkmrtAMN4wm%20uNhNnZO6pcA45yLFuQR86irQ3nKxum%20blMkASiiEKCOCWbA9uE%20IAAi0DvTQBp%20rZwQtJgV5%20M6Dq7fthDzNE%2066JZSDJNS7h4zG20y%20tLT6y4ukABLIdAEWBME1N0jRZkw5ngPJA2yVkpSsZHW5CQOdQeDDekODw8pKaretEgCOkuyaJE8AUEBz0xcEZgclcRg4vw0WA05yRSypyA7uazeutdxPPTHoMouo87haocVN5A8CILoLoy5HmC6FwTDzKg2ARMgCh%202ASAHMuDtBAL-F819ZhxXMNJYAABHUsEQDYUGAEKAA7B0IU6ChQAFZgDN1hPCVAABaAaxCrrEObsAHBHQABsAAODoTCAAMABiGhDCmEdGYaIIAA) for more details

Comment: Then how to define function parameter type to accept objects which values could be string or number?

Comment: that's what your function does. an interface is just not limited to what you defined it to be there. check in the playground, how the interface can easily be declared anew, causing the interfaces (due to the same name) to be merged.

Answer (score 0):

**REVISED:**

You can destructure the object `p` as such when calling the function:

```
fn({ ...p });
```

This takes all of the properties of `p` and puts them on a new object.

It is also possible to create a new object for the purposes of passing to the function:

```
const params = {
    ...p,
};

fn(params);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but `interface Parameters {
    [key: string]: number;
}` has the same behavior as `Record<string, number>` and I am giving type to `p` with `interface` which is parameter for  function in my example  and thats the place when problem occurs

Comment: Please see my revised answer @David